# What type of cleaner should be used to remove "hand sludge" from a varnished wood railing?

Tags: wood, cleaning, handrail

You know what I'm talking about, right? That dark grey sludge that builds up on hand rails over the years? I inherited a case of sludgy hand-rails when I bought my first house and I'd like to clean them.

I've tried using lemon oil-based polish and lots of scrubbing. It helps to an extent, but only on lightly trafficked parts of the rails.

Can anyone recommend a cleaner that will help dissolve this junk but not harm (and preferably protect) the varnished wood?

Comment: What about magic eraser?

Comment: I tried that, actually. It just shredded the magic eraser. I do like those things, though.

Comment: what about this? http://www.fromtimespast.com/HowtoRefinishVarnishedWoodworkwithoutRemoval.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try Murphy's Oil Soap.  It's generally excellent for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest turpentine and 0000 steel wool, alternating with paper towel first.  If not clean enough, Proceed to the ammonia treatment described by 0A0D.  The oil step also sounded good.